# Enabling MapTips in ArcGIS Engine using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

My organization is working on a new version of our software using ArcGIS Engine 10. Previous versions of the software (running on ArcGIS Engine 9.3) displayed MapTips fine as long as they were enabled in the mxd. Our new version running on ArcGIS Engine 10 doesn't display MapTips (and they are fine in the mxd).

Is there any code or setting to enable MapTips, or any known reasons that would cause them to not display in an ArcGIS Engine 10 application?

I have already discovered that layers within a Basemap layer won't display MapTips, so that is not the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The needed setting is:

```
mapControl.ShowMapTips = true;
```

i.e. set the ShowMapTips property on your map control to True.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFeatureLayer thisFeatureLayer = thisLayer as IFeatureLayer;
thisFeatureLayer.ShowTips = true;
```

Comment: An anonymous user notes, "This will programmatically set MapTips to display, but in the case described, the MapTips don't display regardless of the state of this flag."